# (Circular motion) Acceleration is given, so why asked for more?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors, rotational-kinematics

The full question is below.

> A car starts from rest and moves around a circular track of radius $32.0\,\text m$. Its speed increases at the constant rate of $0.500\,\text{m/s}^2$.
> (a) What is the magnitude of its net linear acceleration $15.0\,\text s$ later?
> (b) What angle does this net acceleration vector make with the car’s
> velocity at this time?

In this question, I think it already gives us the acceleration is $0.500\,\text{m/s}^2$, so the net linear acceleration should just be $0.500\,\text{m/s}^2$, right? So, what did the question actually ask for, since it does not even need to calculate?

Comment: They want you to calculate the acceleration that the car has to experience to stay on the circular track in addition. Maybe the use of language in high school physics has changed over the years or I am unfamiliar with the English curriculum, but in general acceleration is acceleration. "net linear acceleration" is a meaningless term, unless we give a special direction vector onto which we want to project the actual acceleration vector. In this case there are two such special vectors: the radial and the tangential vector. The remainder is vector addition.

Comment: I also kind of confused because it seems that the "net linear acceleration" should be the tangential acceleration, but the tangential had already been given, it's kind of weird.

Comment: I think it's a poorly phrased question. I would calculate the total acceleration vector and hand that in. If somebody says "that's wrong", then they really need to explain what "net linear acceleration" is supposed to mean.

Comment: you just calculated it.

Comment: @FlatterMann linear = longitudinal, radial = transverse.

Comment: @JEB I agree. Now we are down to deciphering the meaning of English words, I am afraid. That fits better into English literature than science class, though. A physics homework question should be clear and simple and actually teach something meaningful.

Comment: One more thing: I once was fooled into a wrong answer about "total hydrostatic pressure 25m below the surface of the ocean" by forgetting to add the pressure of the atmosphere on the water. So in your case the teacher may actually want you to realize that "a car" is held on the track by the force of gravity, which adds another 1g acceleration component perpendicular to both, tangential and radial acceleration. It may or may not be a "trick" question to see which students analyze the problem to the fullest. Even if (s)he's not asking... why don't you solve the problem with gravity in addition?

Comment: @FlatterMann I really did not think of the gravity when I did this, you are right, thank you for reminding me, it's really useful and inspiring.

Comment: Yeah, if you do that, just make sure you phrase it carefully. Technically you are not being asked to calculate forces, so the force that holds the car to the ground is not part of the question, but if you want to do the extra work, then calculate the force of the car on the ground (-mg pointing downwards) and add the other forces (tangential accelerating force and centripetal force), otherwise you might get into a discussion with the teacher why the force of the ground on the car has to be caused by a 1g acceleration of the ground UPWARDS... which is not something we teach in high school.

Comment: The answer given by Allure is exactly correct. The word *linear* in "net linear acceleration" is meant to distinguish from angular acceleration, which you have presumably also discussed. The linear acceleration has a component tangential to the circle as well as a component pointed towards its center - the so-called *centripetal acceleration*.

Answer (score 4):

There's one acceleration in the direction of motion (the $0.500m/s^2$) and another towards the center of the track (centripetal acceleration). Presumably the question asks for the magnitude of the vector sum of these two accelerations. This would also fit with the question in (b), since the result will not be in the direction of the car's velocity.